# Eclipse: ctrl+space completion for main no longer works

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse (3.7.1) and I like ctrl+space autocompletion. It used to work for generating a `static public void main(String[] args)` method but no longer does; instead if I type `mai` or `main` and hit Ctrl-space, I get a bunch of `Main` classes.

What's going on, and how can I fix this?

---

for what it's worth, I have Lombok 0.9.3 installed, so I wonder if that's messing things up.

Comment: odd, just tried it in freshly downloaded Eclipse - works fine for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had you been playing around with content assist settings?

One quick try would be going to Window->Preferences and then choosing Java->Editor->Content Assist.

On Content assist property pane press 'Restore Defaults'

or

set "Sort proposals" to "alphabetically" - this should restore default content assist behavior.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I wonder if Lombok is causing this. sigh.

Comment: Aha, if I reset defaults in Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced, then it fixes the problem.

Comment: @JasonS Thank you, I had to do the same (i.e. reset in Advanced not Content Assist). Thanks to ring bearer too for the original suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In your eclipse
Go to Windows-->Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist --> Advanced. Here you have to make sure “Java Proposals” is ticked.
I am sure it will work,it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could select checkbox `public static void main(String[] args)` in `New Java Class` menu.